# How to select an element when either of the elements can be found using Selenium and Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, webdriver, webdriverwait

the quantity button design is different on each load. i have identified them
but i want to proceed when either one element is found.

```
//select quantity 2
//sometimes button A appear
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='quantity']")).click();
Select quantity = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='quantity']")));
quantity.selectByIndex(1); 

//sometimes button B appear
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='amt']")).click();
Select amt = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='amt']")));
quantity.selectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: Do both buttons appear at the same time, or is one button showing and the other one is not present on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findElements()` instead of `findElement()`, that would return a list of web element.

Now, if the size is **1**, your script will get to know that particular element is present. If the size id **0**, then button will not be visible in UI.

Something like this for quantity button :

```
List<WebElement> quantityButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='quantity']"));
if(quantityButton.size()==1){
   quantityButton.get(0).click();
}
```

For amt Button :

```
List<WebElement> amtButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='amt']"));
    if(amtButton.size()==1){
       amtButton.get(0).click();
    }
```

You can write respective else block as per your requirement.

Different approach would be to go with try-catch block.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: i am not sure the logic. how to have the loop to click either one?

Comment: @user2201789 : Both the locators are different, I don't think that you can have loop here and in any situation like that.. the only thing IMO you could do here is to go with try and catch block. Make this question open, let's see if we get more hit on that.

Comment: @cruisepandey : You can use nested loop.

Comment: @KunduK : Could be a shot. If you can write that as an answer, would be really helpful for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

As cruisepandey already provided logic how to handle this kind of scenario.For all your confusion you can try nested if..else loop where it will check the first element size() if it comes `0` if will go inside another loop and check the second element size().

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='quantity']")).size()==0)
{
 if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='amt']")).size()>0)
 {
   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='amt']")).get(0).click(); 
   Select amt = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='amt']")));
   amt.selectByIndex(1); 
 }
 else
 {
   System.out.println("None of the elements present")
 }

}
else
{
  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='quantity']")).get(0).click();
  Select quantity = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='quantity']")));
  quantity.selectByIndex(1); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned *either one element is found* presumably the element is a dynamic element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following Locator Strategies:

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.or(
      ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@id='quantity']")),
      ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@id='amt']"))
  ));
  Select amt = new Select(element);
  quantity.selectByIndex(1);
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.or(
      ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select#quantity")),
      ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select#amt"))
  ));
  Select quantity = new Select(element);
  quantity.selectByIndex(1);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If only one button (actually "select" is appropriate here) then you can modify your XPath to choose either element:

```
WebElement quantityElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='quantity' or @id='amt']"));
Select quantity = new Select(quantityElement);

quantityElement.click();
quantity.selectByIndex(1);
```

Then it doesn't matter which one appears on screen: `//select[@id='quantity' or @id='amt']` — it will match either HTML tag Id.

This will not work if both HTML tags are present in page, but only one is visible at the same time.